# Saving checked boxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I've built a dynamic reading chart with checkboxes so that the person check the chapter they read.

How can I make it possible for the checked ones to be saved so that next time they reopen or reload the page the checked ones won't be unchecked?

This is how my checkboxes are set in the HTML document:

```
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 1
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 2 
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 3
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 4
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 5
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 6
      <input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'>Chapter 7
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. Store something in the LocalStorage, for instance, and read it upon reload.

Comment: What is your back-end on this project?

Comment: Agreed with @JeremyThille or SessionStorage if u need it to expire with the session.

Comment: I'm really a beginner. I forgot to mention that. So, if you guys could give me as much details as possible, it would help me a lot.

Comment: You will have to build a backend for your project if you want your data to be persistent.

Comment: @George I was thinking about giving you some general advice, but I don't know what you want to do. Are you doing this as a homework project, a hobby project, or do you want to become a professional developer?

Comment: @Relequestual, I am doing it as a a hobby project, but to practice what I've been learning. This project could actually be used by some people from my church. I do want to become a professional developer, although I still have a lot to learn, I've been learning  theory but been having a hard time with applying it to real projects.

Comment: @George OK, great. I highly suggest you pick up a web development course from [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&src=ukw&q=web%20development). While there are MANY free courses, some of these are more comprehensive, which is probably what you're looking for. The price for these (right now) are lower than others. Udemy has sales all the time. I can personally vouch for other non web development courses I've purchased.

Comment: You don't have to watch every single video, but can skip to the sections you want to learn about. You can check out the course content before you purchase, and you can normally preview some of the course videos also.

Comment: If you'd like to talk about this further, happy to do so, but SO comments is probably the wrong place... happy to provide a slack link where I'm often found =]

Comment: Relequestual . OK. I'd like to.

Comment: Hello, everybody. I'd like to thank all of you for the comments. With everybody's help, I got the chart working properly. You are all really nice people!

Comment: Ok. Thank you, @Relequestual.

Comment: @George The slack invite link can be found at the bottom of http://json-schema.org

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage method in JavaScript:

```
let checkedChapters = [...];
localStorage.setItem('completedChapters', JSON.strignify(checkedChapters));
```

After that you can get your saved data in app.

```
let checkedChapters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('completedChapters'));
```

We use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() because all saved items has 'string' type

Answer (score 0):

To do this, first you need to add a event listner on input.

```
<input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'  name="check1" onclick='handleClick(this);'>Chapter 1
<input type ='checkbox' class = 'check'   name="check2" onclick='handleClick(this);'>Chapter 2
```

When you click on the checkbox the function handleClick will execute.

```
function handleClick(element){
  if(element.checked){
    localStorage.setItem(element.name, 'true');
  }else{
    localStorage.removeItem(element.name);
  }
}
```

This function add/remove the element from the browser storage (You can check this on Aplication > LocalStorage on element inspector).
Now, to automatcaly check the inputs when the page load you need to add another event listner.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var checkboxList = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxList.length; i++){
    if(localStorage.getItem(checkboxList[i].name) == "true"){
      checkboxList[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

This function walks through your inputs and checks if there is his name on localStorage.

Comment: Thank you ! That is super useful !